# Paragraph processing for Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

Is it possible to get paragraphs of text passed to a Mapper class instead of line by line. I am looking for a ParagraphRecordReader implementation.

Comment: How long is your paragraph? Or what are your cut-off rules?

Comment: Related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711118/multiple-lines-of-text-to-a-single-map

Answer (score 1):

The answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5398215/1660002 sort of answers this requirement. However, you can simply also set the configuration parameter `textinputformat.record.delimiter` to a double newline string (For example: `"\n\n"`) to solve this.

This configurable feature is available in the Apache Hadoop 0.23.x, and 2.x releases, and also in both CDH3 and CDH4 releases from Cloudera if you use those.