# What are the different ways in which we can make a MapReduce program read the data?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, elastic-map-reduce

Actually, I want to perform a computation on a CSV file and for each row of that CSV file, I want to also use the previous four rows for the computation. How can I do that? Almost all the MapReduce examples I have read, the only way data was read was one row at a time and even the computations on different lines were independent of each other. Any resources and good pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: This might also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711118/multiple-lines-of-text-to-a-single-map

Answer (score 0):

The way records are splitted depends on the RecordReader being used. The default *RecordReader* is  *LineRecordReader*, so your records are actually lines. If you want your data to come in chunks of 4 lines, try to implement your own RecordReader that divides data into groups of 4 lines.

http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html

Answer (score 0):

The way you do it is to override `InputFormat` and `RecordReader`.

You can search the web for MultipleLineTextRecordReader.java MultipleLineTextInputFormat.java WholeFileTextInputFormat.java to get started.